# Повторение цикла for n раз

Tags: c++

Нужно заполнить массив латинскими буквами a - z два раза. Как можно это сделать *в одном цикле*? Не хочется повторять код.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char alphabet[26 * 2]; //Двойной латинский алфавит: [a, .., z, a, .., z];

    for (int index = 0, letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; index++, letter++)
        {
            alphabet[index] = letter;
        }
}
```

В коде цикл `for` повторяется 1 раз. Как сделать так, чтобы он повторялся n раз?

***Дополнительный вопрос***

Изначально цикл выглядел так:

```
for (int letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        alphabet[letter] = letter;
    }
```

Данный код выдаёт предупреждение: `переполнение буфера при записи в "alphabet": доступный объём для записи равен "52" байт, однако записать можно только "98" байт.` Я сразу понял, что не так: ASCII код буквы "a" - 97, следовательно, я пытаюсь сделать следующее: `alphabet[97] = 'a';`. Но ошибки я не получаю. Почему? И действительно ли нужно устранить это предупреждение? Может, оставить как есть (а не переписывать цикл, как я сделал)?

Comment: `int index = 0, n = 2; for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter, ++index) alphabet[index] = letter;`

Comment: Выход за границы  массива вызывает неопределённое поведение. Результат не предсказуем. Такие предупреждения устранять нужно.

Comment: @wololo да, точно, спасибо... Решение же было простейшее. А я как всегда пытаюсь какие-то мудрёные решения придумать.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    char alphabet[26 * 2 + 1]; // + нулевой символ

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        char ch = 'a' + i;

        alphabet[i] = ch;      // записываем буквы первого алфавита
        alphabet[i + 26] = ch; // и второго
    }
    alphabet[26 * 2] = '\0'; // указываем, что это конец строки

    std::cout << alphabet << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> я пытаюсь сделать следующее: alphabet[97] = 'a';. Но ошибки я не получаю. Почему? И действительно ли нужно устранить это предупреждение?

Стек — это область памяти, которая создаётся для каждого потока. Каждый раз когда мы объявляем переменную, в стеке сразу после предыдущих объявленных переменных резервируется `sizeof(переменная)` байт.

И если Вы храните данные массива за `sizeof(массив)`, то может произойти такая ситуация, когда состояние другой переменной изменится. И наоборот, когда состояние переменной изменится, изменятся и данные массива.